# AutoCompleteBox selecting the ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got an `AutoCompleteBox` in my application where I can set the `ItemTemplate` like this:

```
<AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
```

But sometimes I want an other `ItemTemplate` to be used:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dictionarytemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In a ListBox I would use a `TemplateSelector` to switch between these two, in the `AutoCompleteBox` I don't have this possibility. How can I accomplish that behavior?

Comment: Are you using any third party control for AutoCompleteTextBox?

Comment: Sorry, wanted to give a fast example, edited my Question.

Comment: What is the condition on which you want to choose the template ?

Comment: Sometimes the Itemssource is a Dictionary<string, string> and sometimes a ObservableCollection<string>. So for the Dictionary I have to take the Second Template